# How can I make Buildcraft pipe not break on single strike?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft

I don't like the fact that [Buildcraft](http://www.mod-buildcraft.com/) pipes break when you hit them: I would like to give them maybe the same durability as cobblestone or something similar.

Is there a way to give buildcraft pipes some measure of durability?

Comment: Perhaps you should link to the mod so that those of us who don't use it can see what it does.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 5):

Your answer is in the `config` folder, goto buildcraft's config folder and open `main.conf`, open it using notepad, and where it says `D:pipes.durability=0.25`, somewhere near the bottom, all you have to do is change the number.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this isn't possible. I think your best bet would be to surround them with blocks. If it isn't possible because there isn't room, I would move your buildcraft stuff to a seperate room and get output and controls somewhere separate. Kind of like how your plumbing is hidden from you in your house. If this is too much work, I'd say your only option would be to edit the source code compile and reinstall.

Comment: That is what I have been doing, I ususaly just use dirt. But when I use the diamond drill from IC2 I can rip through dirt, stone, etc. pretty easily. So there is no setting in the config file durability or anything? I like the idea you about hiding the pipe I might try that instead of just covering them. Thanks.